# Oracle SQL query to find min value from a string comprising of batch number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in my Oracle database called ID, which is a string and has values like 859188_1, 859188_2, 859188_3, ..., 859188_n. The value after '_' is the batch number, i.e 1, 2, 3, ..., n. I need to select the minimum id based on this batch number. Here the minimum value is 859188_1.

Comment: As you see now this is a horrible DB design. You can change your table structure?

Comment: Actually the payload is large and is been split by Oracle Service in batches  and sent to SOA.The first value contains the shipment number and the second is the split batch number.The entire table comes into the picture for controlling the flow in a serialized manner.

Comment: I had the ID based on a DB sequence before and it was working fine.Now the design has been changed.

Comment: Is it Oracle 12c Release 1 or higher?

Comment: What do you mean by "minimum id based on this batch number"? The ID, as you show, combines "shipment number" and "batch number". Do you have several shipments, and for each shipment you need to select the ID that has the lowest batch number? Or what?

Comment: Yes,there will be several shipments and for each shipment I need to select the minimum id.Earlier I was using this query :SELECT min(ID) FROM table WHERE STATE='N' GROUP BY SHIPMENTNUMBER.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
 select id
 from yourTable
 where to_number(regexp_substr(ID, '[^_]+$')) =
   (select min(to_number(regexp_substr(t2.ID, '[^_]+$')))
    from yourTable t2
   )
```

Comment: I was trying to tweak it a little bit. Wanted to pick the minimum out of different shipment numbers on the basis of a flag.Example : If shipment numbers are:  

XXXXX_1    Flag - C
XXXXX_2    Flag - N
XXXXX_3    Flag - N

yyyyyy_1   Flag - C
yyyyyy_2   Flag - N
yyyyyy_3   Flag - N

The filter is also on the basis of Flag where Flag='N'.
The result here should be XXXXX_2 and yyyyyy_2

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the minimum based on the portion *after* the `_`.

If -- as in your example -- the first six characters are all the same, you can simply do:

```
select min(id) keep (dense_rank first order by length(id) asc, id asc) as min_id
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this...

```
with
     inputs ( id ) as (
       select '100_1'  from dual union all
       select '100_3'  from dual union all
       select '100_12' from dual union all
       select '101_3'  from dual union all
       select '101_5'  from dual union all
       select '101_9'  from dual
     )
-- end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select   min(id) keep (dense_rank first 
                       order by to_number(substr(id, instr(id, '_') + 1))) as id
from     inputs
group by substr(id, 1, instr(id, '_') - 1)
;

ID
-----
100_1
101_3
```